# Authoritative source for what features of CSS3 Grid Layout have been implemented by Dartium?

Tags: css, dartium

The latest release of Dartium (34.0.1847.0 (258268)) broke the grid layout in my application that had been working in the previous release. I'm looking for an authoritative source that describes which features of the W3C [CSS Grid Layout Module Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/) are supported in specific Dartium releases (with Experimental Web Platform enabled - if that's where they are implemented) and what CSS nomenclature should be used to access them.

Comment: Apologize - I realized my previous answer did not fully answer your question so I deleted it. However, I still think caniuse.com is a good source for compatibility. Here is the compatibility table for CSS3 Grid Layout: http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS%20grid. Under the 'Resources' tab, you'll see that there is also a polyfill available for Chromium 34.0 (since Dartium is a flavor of Chromium with Dart VM): https://github.com/codler/Grid-Layout-Polyfill

Comment: @dgp It would be the correct table if it had a column for Dartium (something like it is what I had in mind). We're moving to Dart/Polymer.dart/HTML5/CSS3 -- no polyfill.

Comment: Dartium is pretty much a flavor of Chromium with the Dart VM installed, so I would assume that the compatibility table for Dartium 34.0 is very similar to Chrome 34.0.

Comment: @dgp There was partial support as early as Dartium v31 but the chart shows red (no support) from Chromium 31 forward. It might be that the experimental aspects in Dartium are not being tracked. I'm also looking for a fine-grained breakdown of which parts of the specification I can expect to use.

Comment: Although tangentially related to the question, it might be of general interest: Danilo's [presentation](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/03/Get-on-the-CSS-Grid) describes what should be implemented in the latest version. In Chromium/Dartium v34.0.1847, I am able to get example 1 from the Module specification to layout correctly only along the x-axis and not the y-axis. For v33, using property names 'grid-definition-*' instead of 'grid-template-*' as in the spec, the layout was performed correctly.